# How to configure PHPEclipse (Mars 2) with newest running wampserver vor PHP Debugging

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, wampserver

I was searching by google for a good tutorial on how to setup PHPEClipse with a new running wampserver for DEBUGGING!

I often tried to configure Debugging within PHP but never got it to work.

I.e. 
1.) Do I have to create a new PHPEclipse project "PHP Project"?
2.) In which location do i have to create a new PHP Project?
2.1.) Has the location to be in the www-folder (C:\wamp\www) ?
3.) How do i set up the Debugger when pressing the debug-insect-button (ant) in Eclipse?
3.1.) Do i have to choose the WAMPServer somehow here? Which settings do i have to make in the dialog? 
3.2.) Do i have to use xdebug or zend?
3.3.) Is there a way to select PHPDBG?

Cheers and nice weekend!

Comment: WAMPServer comes with XDEBUG already installed

Comment: I downloaded Eclipse PDT to get the PHP functionality

Comment: Never in the `wamp\www\` folder create a subfolder or better still a Virtual Host for each new site/project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a documentation for wampserver and PHP Eclipse like this:

http://www.capri-soft.de/blog/?p=1719

After i found out how to configure, i wrote this documentation. I do not know maybe it was my way of thinking about.

Thank you!